# Show progress bar in .NET CF client from java web service call

Tags: web-services, compact-framework, progress

I have a web service client made with compact framework 2 that call a java web service.
Web service return a byte array that sizes only 200 KB, but in some GPRS connections it delays some minutes. I want to show the progress of the downloaded data with a progress bar, but I haven't found any example. Does anybody knows how do it?
I have found this url, but I think that it isn't for CF clients.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa480520.aspx

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are going to have to keep track of your progress bar on your own.

If your java web service call sends you the total file size, you can set your ProgressBar Maximum to that, otherwise, you have no way of knowing what percentage of the total the data chunk you just received is.

Is that clear?

**Update:**

In the link you posted, the amount of data received in each chunk is define on the line*:

```
int bytesRead 
  = m_oldStream.Read(m_bufferIn, 
  0, 
  m_readSize);
```

This would be the amount you increment your `ProgressBar` **Value**.

*Disclaimer:* I have not spent much time reviewing the code in the link you provided, and my quick analysis of it could be wrong.

Comment: Yes, but if I have de total size file, in which method I receive the data that is downloading. In CF there are Begin and End methods for each web service method, but there isn't any that say the amount of data that is receiving in that moment.